# The set of countable subsets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is it always true that a family of countable sets is always countable?

If I prove that every $A\in B$ is countable is it enough to prove $B$ is countable?

Comment: No, not at all.  For instance, the set of all finite sets of real numbers is uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

The set of natural numbers is countable. As such, the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, consisting of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, is a family of countable sets. However, the power set of a set must have a larger cardinality than that set, so the power set of the naturals is uncountable. In particular, it has cardinality $2^{\beth_0}=\beth_1$.